# C++ destroy object

Tags: c++, object, memory

I am seriously understand the threaten from the memory leak.

I know if I create a pointer, I need to delete it.

But how about I new an object?

Do i need to destroy a by myself?

Does c++ could recollect it by it self?

Comment: You need to destroy the object as well: `delete A` or mem leak

Comment: have you tried compiling the above code?

Comment: No, you don't need to worry about a memory leak here because it's impossible. The code won't compile. (unless you sadisticly give `A` a constructor that takes an `A*` and it doesn't free it)

Comment: *"I know if I create a pointer, I need to delete it."* -- No, you don't.

Answer (score 7):

The correct code would be:

```
A *a = new A();
```

and you would have to destroy it yourself:

```
delete a;
```

You would usually only create an object with new (on the heap),
if you want to make it live longer than the current scope.
If you want to have the object destroyed when leaving the scope, 
you would just allocate it on the stack:

```
{    A a;
}
```

Please make yourself familiar with smart-pointers in case of you have to allocate your objects on the heap -- no need to carry over C programming philosophies from last century!

Answer (score 2):

`new A()` returns a pointer to the object not the object.